# Pagerank in directed *acyclic* graphs (DAG)

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, directed-acyclic-graph, data-mining, ni.networking-internet

I deal with [pagerank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank) computations on large [directed **acyclic** graphs (DAG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph).

I found no reference to work on this specific case, only some work on pagerank in more specific cases, *e.g.*, [PageRank of Scale Free Growing Networks](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/inria-00070168/).

- Does anyone know any reference for DAGs?
- Is there any way to use DAG features to speed pagerank computations up?

A sequel of this question is posted [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/50582/on-line-pagerank-in-a-streaming-dag-directed-acyclic-graph).

Comment: You should be able to compute in closed form the pagerank of a vertex with no incoming edges. And so on for a vertex once all its in-neighbors' pageranks are known. So a topological sort followed by a single pass should do the trick.

Comment: This would be wonderful, and I am amazed that no paper seems to detail this! Still looking for a reference, or I will have to write it myself.

Comment: I am far from an expert but from the definition I see on wikipedia: you need to have non-zero pagerank for the sources of your dag, otherwise it will be $0$ everywhere (seems to be related to so-called "damping factor" in wikipedia). And I agree with usul's comment: $pagerank(u) = f(pangerank(v_1), \dots, pangerank(v_k))$ with $v_1, \dots, v_k$ being ingoing neighbors of $u$ and $f$ being computable with $O(k)$ arithmetic operations so the whole thing is computable in $O(|E|)$ arithmetic operations, where $E$ are the edges ($O(1)$ operations per edge).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested by the comments (thanks!), **the answer is positive** and rather easy.

We want to compute the pagerank of all vertices of a DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph) $G = (V,E)$ with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges. For any vertex $u$, let us denote by $d^+(u)$ its out-degree: $d^+(u) = |\{v, (u,v)\in E\}|$.

Pagerank is basically defined as the stationnary distribution of the following random walk, for a given parameter $\alpha$. The walk starts at a uniformly chosen random vertex. When the walker is at vertex $v$, it goes with probability $\alpha$ to a uniformly random out-neighbor of $v$, and it goes with probability $1-\alpha$ to a uniformly random vertex. If $v$ has no out-going edge, then the walker stays at $v$ with probability $\alpha$.

Then, the probability to be at vertex $x$ after $t$ steps is $p
_t(x) =  \frac{1-\alpha}{n} + \alpha\cdot\sum_{y, (y,x)\in E} \frac{p_{t-1}(y)}{d^+(y)}$. Therefore, the pagerank of any vertex $v$ is $p(v)$ such that
$$
p(v) = \frac{1-\alpha}{n} + \alpha\cdot\sum_{u, (u,v)\in E} \frac{p(u)}{d^+(u)}
$$

Clearly, if a vertex has no in-coming edge, then its pagerank is $\frac{1-\alpha}{n}$.

And, clearly too, if one knows the pagerank of all in-neighbors of a given vertex, the formula above gives the pagerank of this vertex.

As a consequence, one may obtain the pagerank of all vertices in $O(n+m)$ time and space by iteratively processing vertices such that all their in-neighbors have already been processed. An appropriate order may be obtained through a [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) in $O(n+m)$ time and space.

This leads to [new questions on the on-line computation of pagerank in a DAG](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/50582/on-line-pagerank-in-a-streaming-dag-directed-acyclic-graph), that seem more difficult.