# On-line pagerank in a streaming DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph)

Tags: graph-algorithms, directed-acyclic-graph, online-algorithms, streaming-algorithms, topological-sorting

Assume a DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph) is given as a **stream of edges** such that edge $(u,v)$ is given only after all incoming edges of $u$ are given. Let us denote by $n$ and $m$ the number of vertices and edges in this graph. Notice that, here, $n$ is in $O(m)$.

We want to output the pagerank of vertices in this graph **on-line**: we cannot store it nor read it several times, and we want to output pagerank values as soon as possible.

[This question on pagerank in DAG and its answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/50507/pagerank-in-directed-acyclic-graphs-dag) show that this is feasible in $O(n)$ space and $O(m)$ time, if the number $n$ of vertices is known.

**My first questions are:** can we do better for space with a specific ordering of the edge stream? maybe with assumptions on maximal in- and out-degrees?

**Most importantly, the approach above requires that $n$ is known from the beginning. What if $n$ is unknown?**

Since the results depend on $n$, one has to store some information for each of the $n$ vertices and then output the value when one reaches the end of input, which gives $O(n)$ space.

**This leads to my second, more important set of questions:** would it be possible to output some values (or some expressions) such that the pagerank of all vertices can be easily computed from them once $n$ is known? With what space and time complexity?